# Why is git in french?

Tags: git, locale

```
git status
fatal: ni ceci ni aucun de ses répertoires parents n'est un dépôt git : .git
```

locales output:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I know I can fix this by exporting

```
export LANG=en.US
```

to set the language to English. However, I would expect the default language to be English, when no language is configured. Why is git in french with no language configured?

Comment: Is the rest of your system set to a French locale?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's a duplicate, I also installed from brew. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @user1785730 No, leave it for future searches, it's fine.

Comment: It's fine to leave a duplicate question as a pointer to the "master". In fact, it's even encouraged. But you do, you know, actually need to mark it as a duplicate. :-) That's under the "flag" link. You can always mark your own question as a duplicate. I've done it for you here.